# Open link in a HTML in react native webview

Tags: react-native, url, webview

I sucessfully render a HTML file to view using react-native-webview. And when I click on a link  in a view, it loads perfectly on IOS at the same view. But the link doesn't work on Android. It shows 'Cannot download files as permission was denied. Please provide permisson to write to storage, in order to download files'

I've tried to add this line of code to AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` But it downloads as a file to the phone, not in a view of WebView. What did I miss?

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={ Platform.OS === 'ios' 
            ? this.renderHTML(content)
            : this.renderHTMLAndroid(content) 
           }
    domStorageEnabled
    javaScriptEnabled
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to a solution. It doesn't render in a view of webview but open a link in a browser (for Android). It is not really what I want, but at least it works.

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'

loading = (event) => {
       if (event.url.slice(0,4) === 'http') {
           Linking.openURL(event.url)
           return false
       }
       return true
}
```

then in WebView, add

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={ Platform.OS === 'ios'
                               ? null
                               : this.loading
                             }
```